# Why I am receiving the error Error: module ‘string’ has no attribute ‘lower’ when I am using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am new in coding. I am doing the data science path, currently in module introduction to pandas.

I download Jupiter Notebook using Anaconda.

I tried to change all the strings of one column to uppercase or lowercase, but I received the error: “AttributeError: module ‘string’ has no attribute ‘lower’.”

I tried with “upper” instead of “lower” and I received the same error.

I tried: `from string import upper` and returns:
ImportError: cannot import name ‘upper’ from ‘string’ (C:\Users\gustavo\anaconda3\lib\string.py)

Then I tried `import string` and I didn’t receive any error but when I tried: `df[‘estado’] = df.estado.apply[string.upper]`, I have the error: AttributeError: module ‘string’ has no attribute ‘upper’.

I have checked many videos on youtube and I have googled the error but I don’t know how to resolve it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you misunderstand something. `string` is a module not actual data type. In python string data type (i.e. the sequence of characters that forms some text) is called `str` not `string`. `string` is just a module that contains some useful constants and so on. Try for example `a = "hello"; print(a.upper())`

Answer (score 3):

`string.upper` and `string.lower` were in python2. They have been removed from python3, so the `import` fails.

There are a few options:

If you want a one line drop in fix, you can replace

`from string import lower`

with this:

`lower = str.lower`

Better solution is modify your usage everywhere to use methods instead of functions, so replace `lower(s)` with `s.lower()`.

Bigger picture is that the error you encountered indicates that you may be working with code that needs to be ported to python3. See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

Answer (score 1):

To lowercase a pandas column you can use `.str.lower()`, as seen in the documentation ([Vectorized string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html)):

```
df['columname'] = df['columname'].str.lower()
```

If you want to lowercase the whole dataset you can use `apply()` in combination with `asytpe()`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

Comment: The only problem is that is returning me only the column I am changing to lowercase, how can get in my data frame all the original columns, changing only one to lowercase?

Comment: You can use df['columname'] = df['columname'].str.lower()

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a pair of parenthesis, since string.upper() is a function:

```
df[‘estado’] = df.estado.apply[string.upper()]
```

Comment: Hi HarryS, thank you for your help. I tried your suggestion but I still receive the same error :  AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'upper'

Answer (score 0):

This method appears to have been deprecated after Python 2.7, as it appears in the [documentation for string in Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string-functions), but not in the [3.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html) or later.

In this case, you no longer need to perform an import. The code to perform your action, at least for Python 3.9, is as follows:

```
df['estado'] = df.estado.apply(str.upper)
```